# Pyttsx3 Ubuntu aplay:main:831 Error audio open error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, alsa, pyttsx3

I've been trying forever to get my pyttsx code working. I am working in a Github codespace based on Linux Ubuntu. Since it is not my own I can't access any of its settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtK8.png)

I've ran a number of different commands to try to get it to work, including:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install espeak
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

as well as installed libspeak.
The errors unfortunately still persist. Any ideas how to fix it or get around it and still get pyttsx to run?

Comment: If you are in Github Codespace it is a containerized environment, so it doesnt have access to your host audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding these lines to the top of the script:

```
os.system('sudo apt install -y espeak')
os.system('sudo apt-get -y update')
os.system('sudo apt-get install -y alsa-utils')
os.system('sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common')
os.system('sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg')
```